# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0, cant connect to server

Tags: maven

I'm trying to run a server on my laptop and connect to it from my desktop
But every time I get the following error, but if I dig deeper I see
**Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"**
The client does not run if the server is not running.
I tried running the client and the server both on the same computer and it works.
I tried pinging the computers from one another and it works.
I wonder what am I doing wrong?
I'm using Maven.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (client) @ client ---
Exception in Application start method
[WARNING] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1 (LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2 (LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0 (Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect (Net.java:579)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect (Net.java:568)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect (NioSocketImpl.java:585)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:633)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:583)
    at java.net.Socket.<init> (Socket.java:507)
    at java.net.Socket.<init> (Socket.java:287)
    at il.cshaifasweng.OCSFMediatorExample.client.ocsf.AbstractClient.openConnection (AbstractClient.java:136)
    at il.cshaifasweng.OCSFMediatorExample.client.App.start (App.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9 (LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12 (PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10 (PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11 (PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run (InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop (Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3 (WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using       clientSocket= new Socket("MY IP", "MY PORT");
"MY IP" will be inserted as string
"MY PORT" will be inserted as an int\

instead of clientSocket= new Socket(host, port);